# How Can i get a word to break onto a new line in a Span at a certain width?

Tags: css, html

How Can i get a word to break onto a new line in a Span at a certain width?

This is my current code, however I have tried so many things... but the text keeps overflowing the span and not

```
<span style="display:inline-block;width: 70px;word-wrap: break-word;">My Dashboard</span>
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm..works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/FzYFs/ ?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me too. Could be a conflict or error in your other code that's not displayed above.

Comment: What is the name of the browser you testing this project on? and also mention the version of it.

Comment: Works fine for me. Chrome : Version 25.0.1364.152 m